# How does QProcess work on windows

Tags: c++, qprocess

I'm trying to learn how QProcess works and have this kind of code:

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

#include <string>
using std::string;

#include <QtCore/QCoreApplication>
#include <QStringList>
#include <QString>
#include <QProcess>
#include <QIODevice>

#define LINE cout << "\n=====================================\n" << endl;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    LINE;
    cout << "\nstarting process ..." << endl;

    QObject *parent;
    QString program = "make";
    QStringList arguments;
    arguments << "all";
    QProcess *process = new QProcess();

    QString outputFile = "H:\\processOutput.txt";
    process->setStandardOutputFile( outputFile, QIODevice::Append);
    process->setWorkingDirectory( "H:\\sample");
    process->start(program, arguments );

    cout << "\ndone..." << endl;
    LINE;

    return a.exec();
} // end main
```

The process "program" should be run on a the folder "H:\sample" which has two files, main.cpp and Makefile.

My expectation is that "make" will be invoked with the "all" argument. Examining the output of the process (in the file "H:\processOutput.txt") i only see the text "main" and there is no any output of compilation.

Running "make all" on cmd works and yield usual results, main.exe. The whole code seem run to the end because i can see the line "done...".
What am I missing?

Comment: are you sure the command 'make' is on your PATH?

Comment: yes, because if run 'make' on cmd it responds as expected.

Comment: my question was rather that it's a plain cmd, and not something like 'Visual Studio cmd'.. To make sure, execute 'set' as a QProcess to see the environment

Comment: stijn sorry, i do not get your point clearly, do you mean replacing "make" in program for "set" or?

Comment: yeah that's basically it. Call process->start( "set", QStringList() ) and inspect the output in the file, compare it with set executed on your cmd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

QProcess, as the name indicates, starts a separate process, however the process is not bound to an environment map the same way command prompt is.

Since there is no executable `make` in `H:\sample` the process quits immediately. Instead, wrap your call around cmd like this:

```
...
QString program = "%cmdspec%";
QStringList arguments;
arguments << "\\C" << "\"make all\"";
QProcess *process = new QProcess();
...
```

%cmdspec% is a global environmental variable that indicates the default system path to command prompt executable.

Comment: isnt it "/c" vs "\C" ?

refer to "cmd /?"